# cbinding data.table columns specified by a vector of string names?

Tags: r, select, data.table

I have a data.table with many columns:
Let's say a simple example:

```
mm <- data.table( A = 1:4, B = 5:8, C = 5:2, D= c(1,1,1,1))
```

And a vector containing some of its names as strings: (*)

```
nn <- c("A", "B", "C")
```

and I would like cbind the mm content specified by nn as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
5
4
3
2
```

Unfortunately cbind(eval(nn)) is not enough in these cases. 
If A, B and C weren't inside a data.table I could try

```
cbind(lapply(as.list(noquote(c("a","b"))), get))
or
mapply( function(x) cbind(get(noquote(x))), as.list(nn))
```

but they don't work properly.
The only working method I've found so far is

```
unlist(lapply(nn,get))
```

But in my problem they are not independent objects but within the mm data.table, this method doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried

```
mm[, lapply(nn, get)]
```

but it says

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'A' not found

```
lapply(nn,function(x) (mm[,.SDcols=x]))
```

doesn't work either
I've also tried with eval, parse, noquote and other options.

So far I only found this solution:

```
melt(mm[,.SD,.SDcols=nn])$value
```

Is there any simpler method?

(*) Coming from grep operations.

Comment: I prefer your melt approach to the answer below, though you can do `melt(mm[, ..nn])$value`

Comment: @Frank, why do you prefer the melt approach?

Comment: Unlisting preserves names and doesn't warn about combining columns of different types. For example, `DT = data.table(a = as.Date("1978/1/1"), b = 11, v = 2L); melt(DT); unlist(DT)`. Generally, it's because I know what to expect from `melt`... Extending the example with list columns: `DT = data.table(a = as.Date("1978/1/1"), b = 11, v = 2L, k = list(1:2)); unlist(DT); melt(DT, meas=names(DT))` -- seems like the latter is the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a named vector, you can use

```
mm[, unlist(.SD), .SDcols = nn]
```

Or, if you need the result as a data.table, then we can simply wrap the `j` argument inside `.()`

```
mm[, .(unlist(.SD)), .SDcols = nn]
```